# CUDA writes to global memory not seen by other warps

Tags: c++, cuda

I was trying to explain global memory to someone who is new to CUDA. I came up with the following dummy kernel that blocks other threads in other warps until a selected warp sets the global variable to another value:

```cpp
__global__ void with_sync()
{
    while (threadIdx.x / 32 != 0)
    {
        if (is_done != 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (threadIdx.x / 32 == 0)
    {
        is_done = 1;
        printf("I'm done!\n");
    }
}
```

The variable `is_done` is declared outside of the function as a `__device__ __managed__ int` (which, correct me if I'm wrong, means that the the variable will reside in global memory space.

However, when I execute this kernel (1024 1D threads in a single block) like so:

```
with_sync<<<1, 1024>>>();
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
```

`I'm done` is printed out as expected. However, the CUDA program does not terminate (I placed `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` in the host code for it to wait for all threads). This leads me to wonder if the other warps did not receive the change in the `is_done` variable. However, I understand that global memory implies that the value can be seen in device level (i.e. at the very least, all blocks in a grid).

My question is the following: Is there any caching/optimisation done by CUDA that makes it such that this inconsistent global memory view can occur? Is there a way to access the "latest" value from the variable that resides in global memory?

Comment: @RobertCrovella That does not answer why it prints out "I'm done", which means that whatever warp it is running has executed the previous instruction, which is to set the ```is_done``` variable to 1.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Interesting. I ran it on both Volta (Tesla V100) and Pascal (Tesla P4) GPUs and they both act the same way (printing out 32 instances of "I'm done" and stalling).

Comment: Yes, the volta question pertained to your previous code example, where the behavior there might be different.  The volta question isn't relevant for your current code example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any caching/optimisation done by CUDA that makes it such that this inconsistent global memory view can occur? Is there a way to access the "latest" value from the variable that resides in global memory?

Yes, there is caching behavior.  You can modify it with the `volatile` [qualifier](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#volatile-qualifier).

Here is a worked example:

```
$ cat t310.cu
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef USE_VOLATILE
__device__ __managed__ int is_done = 0;
#else
__device__ volatile __managed__ int is_done = 0;
#endif

__global__ void with_sync()
{
    while (threadIdx.x / 32 != 0)
    {
        if (is_done != 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (threadIdx.x / 32 == 0)
    {
        is_done = 1;
        printf("I'm done!\n");
    }
}



int main(){

  with_sync<<<1,1024>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -o t310 t310.cu
$ ./t310
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
^C
$ nvcc -o t310 t310.cu -DUSE_VOLATILE
$ ./t310
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
I'm done!
$
```

(In case its unclear the first run above was terminated by Ctrl-C, due to hang)

Tesla P100 PCIE CUDA 10.0, CentOS 7